# Main.ts for Angular

Tags: angular, program-entry-point

For Google's Tour of Heroes, I realised that for chapter 3, "Create a feature component", file main.ts has to be modified, for the application to be able to start. Anyway, the contents of that file in the corrected project proposed for download has a different content in that file.

So, I re-read the [instructions](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt3) carefully, and I saw nowhere any mention of that file.

Did I miss anything?
Did anybody else also observe this?
Not sure that bootstrap and Protractor are so obvious that there is no need to say, these modifications have been done, for such reasons.

So, is copy/paste the good way to go?

Comment: 1. You don't need to modify the main.ts unless you want to specify a different starting component than `AppComponent`.
2. The change adding Protractor indeed is not needed, this is for e2e tests and probably lasted as a leftover

Comment: Well, I just discovered that, after seeing that in chapter 4, "Add services", the components that were standalone at the end of chapter 3, were registered again in ngModule, with no comment at all on this purpose.
So, I redid chapter 3, but with no standalone component, and it worked jolly well, with no edit in main.ts.
Il was after commenting the contents of app.module.ts that I had to modify main.ts
And I do not find explicit instruction to put all components standalone : I did it to solve an error when HeroDetails was.

Comment: It seems much more simple to create a HeroDetailsComponent with no standalone component.
In this case, it seems the Input wants an initializer.
So I did it like that :
`  @Input() hero: Hero = { id: 0, name: "unknown" };
`

Comment: As I found a solution that works, even if not exactly as described in the Tour of Heroes website, I imagine this thread needs an answer to be closed.
It seems a brief sum up of the comments can do the trick, no?